Natural date parser for chat bot
I need a date parser in Node.js to parse or find dates from the user entered queries.
To design a chat bot - in chatbot user will be asking for a data for a particular date,
so the queries can be in any way. Need to find out which date the user is asking for.
I have tried chrono-node , but its having some drawbacks,
Is there any other natural date parser in Node.js

Offtopic (software libraries recommendation/opinion based):  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424796/5781499

[c++-chrono] is a standard library header introduced in the C++11 standard that provides facilities to represent and manipulate time.  It doesn't look like that tag applies here.
